# List ancestor poms of Maven dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Every time I build my Maven project with a clean ~.m2/ directory, Maven downloads a POM file which is the parent of one my dependencies. This parent pom has SNAPSHOT version.

My project has no SNAPSHOT dependencies at all, so I suspect one of my dependencies was incorrectly released having a parent pom with 'SNAPSHOT'. However, there are dozens of dependencies, so I'm not able to identify which one is causing Maven to pull that snapshot parent pom.

I have tried 'mvn dependency:tree' and also using the Maven enforcer plugin, but their output does not help identifying the culprit.

Is there a Maven command that will list the ancestor poms of my project dependencies?

Comment: I don't think there is, but you might have better clues launching your command with -X and inspecting the output, as the sequence of resolution might give you strong hints about which dependency is causing the issue. Using IntelliJ, in the Maven tool window, you might even have better hints about the resolution issues, as IntelliJ uses an embedded Maven to resolve the projects dependencies, hence being able to provide a better view or tree and issues.

Comment: If you check the output of `dependency:tree` is there a SNAPSHOT in there?

Comment: @khmarbaise there aren't any snapshot entries listed there, as the pom is not a transitive dependency, but the parent of an incorrectly released dependency.

Comment: Ok..Best is to delete the local repository as you did and record the log output during the build and search there for it.